# What is the meaning of a "free energy per unit surface area" vs "pressure" plot?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, surfaces, free-energy, metal-oxide

I don't understand this graph. From the graph, does it mean that at high pressures the oxide layer is stable and this stability reduces at low pressures and temperatures?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The graph does show that at high pressures the $\Delta G$ per surface area values are lower, which would usually indicate stability. I agree with you that as the pressure goes lower, the stability reduces.

However I disagree regarding temperature: As the temperatures decrease (from the green curve denoting 1500K to the blue curve denoting 300K), the $\Delta G$ values are going down, meaning an *increase* in stability.

Comment: To keep things from getting too long here, I migrated the discussion to a [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64178711#64178711)